# How to parse a boolean expression

Tags: parsing, recursion, f#, boolean

I'm pretty new to F#, and I'm trying to use recursion to solve a problem.

The function receives a string, and returns a bool. The string gets parsed, and evaluated. This is bool logic, so

- (T|F) returns true
- (T&(T&T)) returns true
- ((T|T)&(T&F)) returns false
- (F) = returns false

My idea was that every time I found a ), replace the part of the string from the previous ( to that ) with the result of the Comparison match. Doing this over and over until only T or F remains, to return true or false.

EDIT:
I expect it to take the string, and keep swapping out what is in between the ( and ) with the result of the comparison until it comes down to a T or F. What is happening, is an error about an incomplete structured construct. The error is in the for loop.

As I am so new to this language, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Do you see it?

```
let ComparisonSolver (comp:string) =

    let mutable trim = comp
    trim <- trim.Replace("(", "")
    trim <- trim.Replace(")", "")

    match trim with
    | "T" -> "T"
    | "F" -> "F"
    | "!T" -> "F"
    | "!F" -> "T"
    | "T&T" -> "T"
    | "F&F" -> "T"
    | "T&F" -> "F"
    | "F&T" -> "F"
    | "T|T" -> "T"
    | "F|F" -> "F"
    | "T|F" -> "T"
    | "F|T" -> "T"
    | _ -> ""

let rec BoolParser arg =
    let mutable args = arg

    if String.length arg = 1 then 
        match arg with
        | "T" -> true
        | "F" -> false
    else
        let mutable ParseStart = 0
        let endRange = String.length args

        for letter in [0 .. endRange]
            if args.[letter] = "(" then
                ParseStart <- letter
            else if args.[letter] = ")" then
                args <- args.Replace(args.[ParseStart .. letter], ComparisonSolver args.[ParseStart .. letter])
                BoolParser args

let result = BoolParser "(T)&(F)"
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I expect it to take the string, and keep swapping out what is in between the ( and ) with the result of the comparison until it comes down to a T or F. What is happening, is an error about an incomplete structured construct.

Comment: No, I meant what your concrete immediate problem is - which is that your code doesn't even compile because you're getting errors around that `for` loop. It's important to put that in the question because it lets people know whether what they're seeing is what you're seeing so they don't start trying to help you in the wrong places. -- Edit: Yeah, like that. Always be as precise as possible about what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I edited that into the main post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to parse a boolean expression. It might be a good idea to look at the excellent library FParsec.

http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/

Another way to implement parsers in F# is to use Active Patterns which can make for readable code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns

It's hard to provide good error reporting through Active Patterns but perhaps you can find some inpiration from the following example:

```
let next s i = struct (s, i) |> Some

// Skips whitespace characters
let (|SkipWhitespace|_|) struct (s, i) =
  let rec loop j =
    if j < String.length s && s.[j] = ' ' then
      loop (j + 1)
    else
      next s j
  loop i

// Matches a specific character: ch
let (|Char|_|) ch struct (s, i) =
  if i < String.length s && s.[i] = ch then
    next s (i + 1)
  else
    None

// Matches a specific character: ch
//  and skips trailing whitespaces
let (|Token|_|) ch =
  function
  | Char ch (SkipWhitespace ps) -> Some ps
  | _                           -> None

// Parses the boolean expressions
let parse s =
  let rec term =
    function
    | Token 'T' ps                        -> Some (true, ps)
    | Token 'F' ps                        -> Some (false, ps)
    | Token '(' (Parse (v, Token ')' ps)) -> Some (v, ps)
    | _ -> None
  and opReducer p ch reducer = 
    let (|P|_|) ps = p ps
    let rec loop l =
      function
      | Token ch (P (r, ps))  -> loop (reducer l r) ps
      | Token ch _            -> None
      | ps                    -> Some (l, ps)
    function
    | P (l, ps) -> loop l ps
    | _         -> None 
  and andExpression ps  = opReducer term           '&' (&&) ps
  and orExpression ps   = opReducer andExpression  '|' (||) ps
  and parse ps          = orExpression ps
  and (|Parse|_|) ps    = parse ps
  match (struct (s, 0)) with
  | SkipWhitespace (Parse (v, _)) -> Some v
  | _                             -> None

module Tests = 
  // FsCheck allows us to get better confidence in that the parser actually works
  open FsCheck

  type Whitespace = 
    | Space

  type Ws = Ws of (Whitespace [])*(Whitespace [])

  type Expression =
    | Term  of Ws*bool
    | And   of Expression*Ws*Expression
    | Or    of Expression*Ws*Expression

    override x.ToString () =
      let orPrio              = 1
      let andPrio             = 2
      let sb                  = System.Text.StringBuilder 16
      let ch c                = sb.Append (c : char)  |> ignore
      let token (Ws (l, r)) c = 
        sb.Append (' ', l.Length) |> ignore
        sb.Append (c : char)      |> ignore
        sb.Append (' ', r.Length) |> ignore
      let enclose p1 p2 f     = 
        if p1 > p2 then ch '('; f (); ch ')'
        else f ()
      let rec loop prio =
        function
        | Term (ws, v)    -> token ws (if v then 'T' else 'F')
        | And  (l, ws, r) -> enclose prio andPrio <| fun () -> loop andPrio l; token ws '&' ;loop andPrio r
        | Or   (l, ws, r) -> enclose prio orPrio  <| fun () -> loop orPrio l ; token ws '|' ;loop orPrio r
      loop andPrio x
      sb.ToString ()

    member x.ToBool () =
      let rec loop =
        function
        | Term (_, v)     -> v
        | And  (l, _, r)  -> loop l && loop r
        | Or   (l, _, r)  -> loop l || loop r
      loop x

  type Properties() =
    static member ``Parsing expression shall succeed`` (expr : Expression) =
      let expected  = expr.ToBool ()  |> Some
      let str       = expr.ToString ()
      let actual    = str             |> parse
      expected      = actual

  let fscheck () =
    let config = { Config.Quick with MaxTest = 1000; MaxRejected = 1000 }
    Check.All<Properties> config
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you need to correct.

- `for letter in [0 .. endRange]` is missing a `do` at the end of it - it should be `for letter in [0 .. endRange] do`
- The `if` comparisons in the `for` loop are comparing `chars` with `strings`. You need to replace `"("` and `")"` with `'('` and `')'`
- `for letter in [0 .. endRange]` will go out of range: In F# the array construct `[x..y]` will go from `x` to `y` *inclusive*. It's a bit like in C# if you had `for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++)`. In F# you can also declare loops like this: `for i = 0 to endRange - 1 do`.
- `for letter in [0 .. endRange]` will go out of range again: It's going from `0` to `endrange`, which is the length of `args`. But `args` is getting shortened in the `for` loop, so it will eventually try to get a character from `args` that's out of range.

Now, the problem with the `if..then..else` statements, which is what I think you were looking at from the beginning.

```
if args.[letter] = '(' then
 ParseStart <- letter
else if args.[letter] = ')' then
 args <- args.Replace(args.[ParseStart .. letter], ComparisonSolver args.[ParseStart .. letter])
 BoolParser args
```

Let's take the code within the two branches as two separate functions.

The first does `ParseStart <- letter`, which assigns `letter` to `ParseStart`. This function returns `unit`, which is F# equivalent of `void`.

The second does:

```
args <- args.Replace(args.[ParseStart .. letter], ComparisonSolver args.[ParseStart .. letter])
BoolParser args
```

This function returns a `bool`.

Now when you put them together in an `if..then..else` statement you have in one branch that results a `unit` and in the other in a `bool`. In this case it doesn't know which one to return, so it shows an "expression was expected to have type" error.

I strongly suspect that you wanted to call `BoolParser args` from *outside*
 the for/if loop. But it's been indented so that F# treats it as part of the `else if` statement.